# change background color of wp8 app layout

Tags: windows-phone-8, background, themes

I'm interested to know, How can I change the background color through programming in WP8 App. When I navigate between the pages in my app, the background color that appears is visible at the moment of swiping pages which is either white or black(depends on theme)

Today I had downloaded `Imagefusion` app from the Store, where background color you see while navigating between pages is light beige, but not white/black. Do you know how can I change the background color of the app layout? Thank you.

I'm using c#, visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

you must be having Grid at top most layer say `gridRoot`

then, If you want to change its background color programmatically then use:

```
gridRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.YourColor);
```

As you haven't set background color to Grid, it shows default color i.e. your theme color.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0fddd42-ecb9-4a2b-b5e5-10f464cdf3e6/change-background-other-than-dark-or-light-in-app?forum=wpdevelop

Here is the easiest way that fits my expectations. I guess this method also works. Thank you very much for your help.